# Can I enter Singapore after being told I was banned?

Tags: legal, singapore, deportation, criminal-records

I worked in Singapore for 7 years beginning in 2003. In 2010 I was convicted and went to prison for 2.5 years. I was released in 2013, and was sent back to Malaysia.

I was told that I'm banned from entering Singapore again for my entire life.

Is it really impossible for me to go to Singapore again? What should I do to raise the ban, and where can I check if I'm still banned?

Comment: This really sounds like a legal question - and I'm really having a difficult time following this.

Comment: Some edits have been made to make this more readable.  Please check to make sure it accurately states your question.

Comment: This sounds like a question for a lawyer who practices immigration law in Singapore.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should be asked of an attorney.

Comment: Why in the world would you expect any country that had put you in prison for 2.5 years would want to let you in again??

Answer (score 12):

You're out of luck. Under the Singapore Immigration Act you are specifically prohibited under Part II, Sec. 8, Para 3d:

> (d) any person who —
>
> (i) has been convicted in any country or state of an offence for which a sentence of imprisonment has been passed for any term;
>
> (ii) has not received a free pardon; and
>
> (iii) by reason of the circumstances connected with that conviction is deemed by the Controller to be an undesirable immigrant;

[Source](http://statutes.agc.gov.sg/aol/search/display/view.w3p;ident=fc5a649b-d9a3-413f-80c5-f5f8bd5e309e;page=0;query=DocId%3A%22d0fd4d9d-0e2f-462f-a0df-0df7ecdc86d1%22%20Status%3Apublished%20Depth%3A0;rec=0#pr8-he-.)

Further on in Part V there are paragraphs describing the powers to deny disembarkation, or to detain.

I didn't find any reference to any form of limitations on these paragraphs, implying that they apply until the government changes the law to say they don't. There are some provisions for exemptions at the discretion of the Minister and/or Controller of Immigration - I doubt you'd qualify.

All that said, I am not a lawyer. If you seriously hope to be admitted legally to Singapore any time soon (or at all) you should find one.